# Getting undefined reference when trying to build a pybind11 project using gcc

Tags: c++, g++, python-c-api, pybind11

I am trying to build a C++ static library in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 in my case) using GCC using a `Makefile`. I noticed the issue is not with the makefile itself but the way I'm trying to compile and build with GCC.  Before I explain a bit more on the GCC side, here is how my current project hierarchy looks like.

The project uses `Pybind11` header only library which resides in the `External_Libraries` directory.

My class definition and implementation, naming `Core.h` and `Core.cpp` reside in `Internal_libraries` along with `py_utilities.h` and `any.hpp` which contain some utility functions. (These two files are not used though). and finally `test_lib.cpp` which uses `Core.h` resides in the root.

This is how it looks :

```
MainDirectory  
 ┣ External_Libraries  
 ┃ ┗ Pybind11    
 ┃   ┗ Pybind11    
 ┃     ┗ Include      
 ┃ 
 ┣ Internal_Libraries  
 ┃ ┣Core.h  
 ┃ ┣Core.cpp  
 ┃ ┣py_utilities.h  
 ┃ ┣any.hpp  
 ┃
 ┗test_lib.cpp
```

Now, the project as you can see, depends on `Pybind11` include directories and also `<Python.h>` plus pythons lib directories. I face the same undefined errors both when I try to build the static library or the normal executable. I include the needed search paths (include and library) to the GCC like  this :

- Building `Core.o`:

```sh
g++ -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages -c ./Internal_Libraries/Core.cpp -o Core.o
```

- Building `test_lib.o`:

```sh
g++ -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages -c test_lib.cpp -o test_lib.o
```

and finally :

- Building `test_lib` executable:

```sh
g++ -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages test_lib.o Core.o -o test_lib
```

This is where it fails and I get lots of undefined errors which I guess is related to the linker, however I provided the needed paths, so I'm at a loss what's gone wrong here!

These are the errors I get:

```
g++ -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages test_lib.o Core.o -o test_lib
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11::cast_error::set_error() const':
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv[_ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv]+0x29): undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv[_ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv]+0x34): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11::error_scope::error_scope()':
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind1111error_scopeC2Ev[_ZN8pybind1111error_scopeC5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `PyErr_Fetch'
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11::error_scope::~error_scope()':

...

Core.o: In function `std::enable_if<((!std::is_floating_point<int>::value)&&std::is_signed<int>::value)&&((sizeof (int))<=(sizeof (long))), pybind11::handle>::type pybind11::detail::type_caster<int, void>::cast<int>(int, pybind11::return_value_policy, pybind11::handle)':
Core.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail11type_casterIivE4castIiEENSt9enable_ifIXaaaantsrSt17is_floating_pointIT_E5valuesrSt9is_signedIS6_E5valuelestS6_stlENS_6handleEE4typeES6_NS_19return_value_policyESA_[_ZN8pybind116detail11type_casterIivE4castIiEENSt9enable_ifIXaaaantsrSt17is_floating_pointIT_E5valuesrSt9is_signedIS6_E5valuelestS6_stlENS_6handleEE4typeES6_NS_19return_value_policyESA_]+0x2c): undefined reference to `PyLong_FromSsize_t'
Core.o: In function `pybind11::array_t<unsigned char, 16>::ensure(pybind11::handle)':
Core.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind117array_tIhLi16EE6ensureENS_6handleE[_ZN8pybind117array_tIhLi16EE6ensureENS_6handleE]+0x70): undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
Core.o: In function `pybind11::array_t<unsigned char, 16>::raw_array_t(_object*)':
Core.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind117array_tIhLi16EE11raw_array_tEP7_object[_ZN8pybind117array_tIhLi16EE11raw_array_tEP7_object]+0x26): undefined reference to `PyExc_ValueError'
Core.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind117array_tIhLi16EE11raw_array_tEP7_object[_ZN8pybind117array_tIhLi16EE11raw_array_tEP7_object]+0x35): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is the link to the full error log : [error log](https://pastebin.com/9Rr6JPy3)

In case the contents of `Core.h` is important here it is :

```cpp
#ifndef CORE_H

#define CORE_H



/* If we are we on Windows, we want a single define for it.*/

#if !defined(_WIN32) && (defined(__WIN32__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__MINGW32__))

 #define _WIN32

#endif /* _WIN32 */


#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_CORE_BUILD_DLL)

/* We are building CORE as a Win32 DLL */

 #define CORE_API __declspec(dllexport)

#elif defined(_WIN32) && defined(CORE_DLL)

/* We are calling CORE as a Win32 DLL */

 #define CORE_API __declspec(dllimport)

#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(_CORE_BUILD_DLL)

/* We are building CORE as a shared / dynamic library */

#define CORE_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))

#else

/* We are building or calling CORE as a static library */

 #define CORE_API

#endif


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;

typedef void(*CallbackFn)(bool, std::string, py::array_t<uint8_t>&);
typedef std::function<void(std::string)> LogFunction;
typedef void * HANDLE;


class CORE_API Core

{
private:
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::object serviceUtilsModule;
    py::object cls;
    py::object obj;
    py::object startFunc;
...



public:

    Core();
    Core(bool showFeed);
    Core(LogFunction logInfo);
    Core(LogFunction logInfo, LogFunction logWarning);
    Core(LogFunction logInfo, LogFunction logWarning, LogFunction logDebug);
    Core(LogFunction logInfo, LogFunction logWarning, LogFunction logDebug, std::vector<CallbackFn> callbackList);
...
    ~Core();


    void Start(bool async= false);
    py::list GetCallbacks(void);
...
    static void DefaultLoger(std::string str);
};



extern "C"

{
    //COREAPI wchar_t** GetResults(wchar_t* word, int* length, int threshold = 9);
    CORE_API void Start(bool);
    CORE_API void Stop(void);
    CORE_API void SetCpuAffinity(int mask);
    CORE_API void AddCallback(CallbackFn callback);
    CORE_API void RemoveCallback(CallbackFn callback);
    CORE_API void* GetCallbacks(void);
    CORE_API void DefaultLoger(char* str);

    CORE_API void*  CreateHandle();
    CORE_API void*  GetCurrentHandle();
    CORE_API void   DisposeCurrentHandle();
    CORE_API void   SetCurrentHandle(void* handle);
    CORE_API void*  GetHandle();
    CORE_API void   DisposeHandle(void*);

}



#endif // !CORE_H
```

The project works fine under Windows and Visual C++ v14 (VS2015) and now I'm trying to do the same thing in Linux using GCC. It seems I'm doing something wrong obviously but I can't seem to know where I have gone wrong. What am I missing here?

### Update

After following this [link](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually) on manually compile pybind11, I ended up doing :

```sh
g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -fPIC -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages -c ./Internal_Libraries/Core.cpp -o Core.o
g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -fPIC -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages -c test_lib.cpp -o test_lib.o
g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -fPIC -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages test_lib.o Core.o -o test_lib
```

Please note that, I removed the `shared` keyword from the commands above so it doesn't create the shared library! Having said that the last command still gives linker errors:

```
 g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -fPIC -I./External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include -I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages test_lib.o -o test_lib
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11_static_get':
test_lib.cpp:(.text.pybind11_static_get[pybind11_static_get]+0x3): undefined reference to `PyProperty_Type'
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11_static_set':
test_lib.cpp:(.text.pybind11_static_set[pybind11_static_set]+0x12): undefined reference to `PyProperty_Type'
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11::cast_error::set_error() const':
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv[_ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv]+0x10): undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv[_ZNK8pybind1110cast_error9set_errorEv]+0x1c): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
test_lib.o: In function `pybind11::detail::translate_exception(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr)':

...


test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE[_ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE]+0x9a): undefined reference to `PyTuple_Size'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE[_ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE]+0xaa): undefined reference to `PyTuple_GetItem'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE[_ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE]+0xd3): undefined reference to `PyObject_Str'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE[_ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE]+0x1cc): undefined reference to `PyDict_Contains'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE[_ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE]+0x3c1): undefined reference to `PyDict_Contains'
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE[_ZN8pybind116detail5printENS_5tupleENS_4dictE]+0x518): undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'
test_lib.o: In function `void pybind11::print<(pybind11::return_value_policy)1, pybind11::list>(pybind11::list&&)':
test_lib.cpp:(.text._ZN8pybind115printILNS_19return_value_policyE1EJNS_4listEEEEvDpOT0_[_ZN8pybind115printILNS_19return_value_policyE1EJNS_4listEEEEvDpOT0_]+0x21): undefined reference to `PyDict_New'
test_lib.o: In function `main':
test_lib.cpp:(.text.startup+0x34): undefined reference to `Core::Core(bool)'
test_lib.cpp:(.text.startup+0x41): undefined reference to `Core::SetCpuAffinity(int)'
test_lib.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4b): undefined reference to `Core::Start(bool)'
test_lib.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5b): undefined reference to `Core::GetCallbacks()'
test_lib.cpp:(.text.startup+0x85): undefined reference to `Core::GetCallbacks()'
test_lib.cpp:(.text.startup+0x107): undefined reference to `PyObject_Str'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Update 2

Looking at the errors, it seems to me the issue isnot pybind11 itself, but the **Python libraries**. `PyObject_Str`,`PyObject_Str`, `PyImport_ImportModule`, `PyProperty_Type` ,etc are all Python C APIs.  However I'm providing the Python include and especially the libs directory, so g++ should be able to find the libs and link them. I'm at a loss here why this doesn't work. What is missing here?

I even made a bash file and tried all paths I've found to no avail:

```sh
#!/bin/bash  

PYBIND_INCL_DIR=-I/home/rika/Documents/cpp/External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include
PYTHON_INCL_DIR=-I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m
PYTHON_INCL_DIR2=-I/home/rika/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.4-h265db76_1/include/python3.7m

PYTHON_LIB_DIRS=-L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/
PYTHON_LIB_DIRS2=-L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
PYTHON_LIB_DIRS3=-L/home/rika/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.4-h265db76_1/lib/

# echo $PYBIND_INCL_DIR
# echo $PYTHON_INCL_DIR

g++ $PYBIND_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS2 $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS3 -c Core.cpp -o Core.o
g++ $PYBIND_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS2 $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS3 test_lib.cpp Core.o -o test_lib
```

Comment: Because `gcc` is for C and `g++` is for C++

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks a lot for the correction. I used g++ instead and the issue still persists.

Comment: Still, because you did not link to pybind11 .. https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually

Comment: isnt g++ itself linking automatically? how should I link against pybind11? ok thanks a lot. I'll look into it

Comment: What should I be using instead of shared in that example? cause removing it, causes the last command to build the executable to generate the same errors again (updated the question)

Comment: Have you followed the steps [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually)? In particular note the flags `-shared -fPIC` and the output extension suffix specified by `python3-config --extension-suffix`

Comment: @ChrisD: yes, but I dont want to create a shared lib, that command is specifically used to creae a shared lib if im not wrong.

Comment: Most python extensions are shared libraries. Unless you're planning to rebuild the interpreter with your extensions permanently included.

Comment: @ChrisD , Im not building an extension, I'm embedding the interpreter in a C++ application. the project builds just fine under visual studio, however, I'm having a nightmare with gcc at the moment!

Comment: I see. In that case you probably want to make sure you are passing whatever is specified by `python3.x-config --ldflags`

Comment: @ChrisD Thanks alot. using the -lpython3.7m everything builds just fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
As I said, the linker errors were related to the Python library not being found. In order to have a successful build, thus one, needed to only include that library, so the final build command would be :

```
PYBIND_INCL_DIR=-I/home/rika/Documents/mahsan_FV/cpp/External_Libraries/pybind11/pybind11/include
PYTHON_INCL_DIR=-I/home/rika/anaconda3/include/python3.7m
PYTHON_LIB_DIRS=-L/home/rika/anaconda3/lib/

g++ $PYBIND_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS -c Core.cpp -o Core.o 
g++ $PYBIND_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_INCL_DIR  $PYTHON_LIB_DIRS test_lib.cpp Core.o -lpython3.7m -o test_lib
```

This simply compiles and links all the object files together and solves the issue.

### More Explanation:

You can get this either by navigating to the Python lib directory or simply 
executing `python3-config --ldflags` or `python3.7-config --ldflags` (depending on your version of python if you have several installations) in your terminal.(Thank you @[ChrisD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3793674/chrisd))

However, in order for the executable to be run properly, the lib folder needs to be in PATH or one could also use `ldconfig` to load the needed library. :
I had to also do :

```
sudo ldconfig /home/rika/anaconda3/lib/
```

Side note:
I also found [this website](https://www.slothparadise.com/c-libraries-linking-compiling/) very helpful on the linking procedure. 
I also tried to directly use the library which was:

```sh
home/hossein/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.4-h265db76_1/lib/libpython3.7m.a
```

which resulted in the error :

```sh
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file ‘/home/rika/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.4-h265db76_1/lib/libpython3.7m.a’ generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 6.2
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: g++ returned 1 exit status
```

proving the only way to get the linking right was to use `-lpython3.7m`!

Comment: You can probably set an [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) for the runtime linking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into it. really appreciate your help